# Foundation 6 Responsive Toggle nav not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am doing my first project in Foundation 6 and am having trouble getting the responsive navigation to work. I started with the basic page template that comes with Foundation (installed F6 using CodeKit) then I pasted in the responsive menu code exactly as it appears here http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html#responsive-toggle  but when viewed at small screen sizes, the word "menu" appears, but clicking it does nothing.

The Drilldown responsive menu also does not work -- pasted in the drilldown menu code (second example down, on the page referenced above) and what appears is a long long list of links, nothing is collapsed and nothing slides in. There must be a script missing but I have triple-checked and app.js, foundation.js and jquery scripts are loaded. What else am I missing?

Comment: Just started a new Foundation 6 project with the basic template using CodeKit and the Responsive Toggle and the Drilldown work fine for me. You have any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 3):

First of all sorry for my bad English, did you initialize foundation's javascript?
That can be done with the following code in youre custom javascript file:

```
    $(document).foundation();
```

I do it with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

for more information see: [Foundation-6 documentation - initializing](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing)

and please check if you have the proper file structure for the foundation files, please see the following documentation: [Foundation-6 documentation - File Structure](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#file-structure)

Comment: `$(document).foundation();` should be all that is needed to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Faulty purifycss configuartion in the gulp.babel.js file.**

I also had this problem. My setup:

- [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp)
- [webapp's jade recipe](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/jade.md)

I can get the responsive dropdown menu to work by using the tab and enter key. This means that the relevant js files are being loaded correctly. The navigation 'burger' also does not appear.

Upon using the chrome dev tools to inspect the responsive dropdown menu example from the foundation website, I noticed that style of `<button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle=""></button>` is being effected by the `.menu-icon` CSS rule from the scss partial, _menu-icon.scss. Mine wasn't. When I looked, the **foundation.scss** file from the **app/** has the exact same style rule. The converted **foundation.css** was being served from the **.tmp/** folder, but did not have the `.menu-icon` CSS rule. Then I suspected purifycss again (which I had commented out of the gulp file before and forgot to reset the gulp serve, saw no fix and thus falsely excluded the purifycss rule from the list of suspects).

I set my gulp styles task up like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass.sync({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: ['.']
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']}))
    /*Stupidly assumed that purifycss supported jade files as src files*/
    .pipe($.purifycss(['app/**/*.js', 'app/*.jade']))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Which meant that the necessary styles were being deleted (including `.menu-icon`). I think I will use stylperjade or rearrange the tasks so that I can do this: `.pipe($.purifycss(['app/**/*.js', '.tmp/*.jade']))`\

Let me know if this was your solution as well